# Checking if a set is bounded

Tags: optimization

[image]

While proving boundedness, how did we reach the maximum limits of x2 and x3 in A (the last line)?

Comment: Hi Lucifer. What is $\pi$? What is $A$? I think we are missing some context here.

Comment: π is just some function here that needs to be maximised. And A, as defined in the question, is the set of (x1,x2,x3) which meets the conditions.